# Linear search array

Tags: java, arrays

Im working on a project in which it reads book titles in from a .txt file and puts them into an arraylist, then the arraylist is converted to an array, The user enters a number which is the books reference number, then it does a linear search to find that book. Im just having a little trouble with the code for my linear search, heres what I have:

```
 private void FindItActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
String input;
int int1;
input = Input.getText();
int1 = Integer.parseInt(input);

for(int i=0; i<bookList.length; i++){
if (bookList[i].equals(int1)){
    Output1.setText("The Book is " + bookList[i]);
}

}


}
```

It says .equals() on incompatible types, not sure how to fix, thanks for any help you may be able to offer

```
  public class Book{
String referenceNumber, title;

public Book(String _referenceNumber, String _title){
   referenceNumber = _referenceNumber;
   title = _title;
}
}

ArrayList <Book> Books = new ArrayList <Book> ();
Book [] bookList;
```

Here is the Book class and arrays

Comment: is your `booklist` string ? If so, just compare it to `input` itself.. `bookList[i].equals(input)`

Comment: What is the declaration for bookList ?

Comment: Please add `Book` class details too

Answer (score 2):

`bookList[i].referenceNumber.equals(input)`

This should solve your compatibility problem

On side note, not a good idea to make your class members public..try using getters and setters to change the members..

Answer (score 0):

A little more details: as GoldRoger correctly pointed out, you need to access the referenceNumber of your book. It says incompatible types because you are comparing apples against carrots, or better said Numbers against Books. Accessing the referenceNumber of the book through:

```
bookList[i].referenceNumber.equals(input)
```

is the correct approach.